# AngularJS Model Logic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I would like some advice on how best to include logic within my model.  Below is a simplified version of my model.  I have some logic that should be included with start/pause/complete task before the http call is run, but I'm unsure where to include it.  I saw a post about using prototype to extend my model, but that didn't seem to work with the $resource.  It seems like this would be a very common need, but I couldn't find any posts that provided a good explanation.

```
angular.module('myModels', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Tasks', function($resource){

    return $resource(':url', {},
        {
        'query':        {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray:true,
            url: '/tasks/:id.json'
        },
        'startTask':        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/tasks/task_start/:id.json'
        },
        'pauseTask':        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/tasks/task_pause/:id.json'
        },
        'completeTask':     {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/tasks/task_complete/:id.json'
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run some tasks everytime before and/or after http request you may use 
$httpProvider interceptors

Here is documentation with example [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: It appears that the $httpProvider interceptors will act on all http requests.  Is this correct?  What I'm looking for is how best to add code to a specific factory that uses $resource (or $http).  For example, with the tasks shown above I'd like to convert a task status code to a word when getting tasks and include that with the task objects.  One method that came to mind was to use my existing code as low level functions, then add a level above it that would represent my model functions.  This would be similar to how you abstract your model from your database calls on the server. Thoughts?